# Read from a realtime API and store all messages

Tags: database, postgresql, real-time, nosql

I'm looking for a tool to read events from a series of realtime APIs and store them in a database for processing later.

I've hobbled something together in Python and Postgres but Postgres has become slow I presume as it's so write heavy.

Before I go and build this, I was thinking there might well be something which can do this for me already? Or if not, what would be a good tool for this job? Logstash?

Thanks

Comment: Have to tried to tune things to increase write performance? For example, you could try to disable synchronous commits with `SET synchronous_commit TO off;`. This can be done on a per transaction basis.

Comment: What you want is a message queue.